# jQuery ajax, send form with input type file and Json

Tags: jquery, ajax, file

I have a form with several inputs and other field.

I have a save button, and when I click, I send the form with ajax with jQuery :

```
$.ajax({
        type:       "POST",
        dataType:   "json",
        url:        $('#ajaxUrl').val(),
        data:       "action=save&" + form.serialize()
});
```

So, when I have only simple input like text, select etc.. it's ok. But if I have an input type file, I can't retrieve my file. $_FILES is always empty.

How can I do that as simply as possible ?

Edit : I don't want to use a plugin :)

Comment: Using [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Comment: @Clément Andraud, not sure, whether this will help you out or not, But please have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71170/how-do-i-upload-import-form-input-files-via-ajax-function
You may get some idea.

Answer (score 3):

Implementation for ASP.NET MVC:

To start making your form-wrapper :

```
<form id="inputform">
    <input class="hide" type="file" name="file" id="file" />
</form>
```

Сreate a client-handler to send:

```
$("#yourButton").bind('click', function () {
    var data = new window.FormData($('#inputform')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        xhr: function () {  
            return $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: "@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")",
        success: function () { },
        error: function () { },
    });
});
```

Do handler on the server side (controller):

```
    public ActionResult MethodName(HttpPostedFileWrapper file) {
    var img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
       ....
       return ..;
    }
```

I hope this will help you save time ;)

Answer (score 1):

`form.serialize` does not manage file inputs. You'll have to an XMLHttpRequest with `formData` as adeneo suggests, see [example usage here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery?rq=1). For older browsers, there are solutions using iframe and POSTing the form with the iframe as target. Some jquery plugins will do all that for you, like, say, [JQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) (but plenty of others exist).

Comment: Support for formData start in IE10, that's why i'll suggest too to use a plugin which use iframe for support older browser. +1

Comment: Hum, my problem, i work on a custom CMS. The function for save a new content is already write.. So if i can just edit this script and no rewrite all... ^^

Comment: Well if you can drop support of older browsers, you can just edit your script to use formData. If you can't (dropping IE 8 & 9 is pretty drastic), I'm afraid that you're gonna have to go a little further. But some plugins will do all of the heavy-lifting, so it shouldn't be very complicated.

Comment: Do you know a very simplist plugin ?

Comment: The one listed by LeftyX seems simple enough

Answer (score 0):

I've used this [jQuery plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) which has capabilities to [upload files](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload).

**HTML:**

```
<form action="file-echo2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
</form>
```

**Javascrtipt:**

```
$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {

    },
    success: function() {

    },
    complete: function(xhr) {

    }
});
```

Comment: i'd do the same comment as for streetpc's answer +1

Answer (score 0):

I found this [little "vanilla" framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files) by querying "Using FormData Objects" on google.

used by:

```
AJAXSubmit(myForm);
```

just modify on

```
function ajaxSuccess (){/*here*/}
```

if you console.log() the response on  `ajaxSuccess`  you could see the data submitted to server. It is on `submittedData` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Note - your form tag should have enctype="multipart/form-data"
# Try this

     var xdata = new FormData();
     var files = $('#xfile')[0].files;
     xdata.append('xfile',files[0]);

# This is how you add additional data
# You can loop through this if you have many fields in your form
     xdata.append('action', 'save');

     jQuery.ajax({    
          data:xdata,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          type:"post",
          url:"yourfilename.php" 
     })

# You can retrieve it as
$_FILES['xfile'];
```